# Spring MVC ignores configured PropertyEditor and uses constructor instead

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Using Spring 3.1 and given this kind of thing:

```
class Thing {
  public Thing() {}
  public Thing(String someProperty) {}
}

class ThingEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) {
        if (text != null) {
            Thing thing = new Thing(text); // or by using a setter method
            setValue(thing);  

        }

    }
}

class SomeController {
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Thing.class, new ThingEditor());
    }
}
```

I found that the registered property editor was not being called unless I removed the constructor that takes a String in `Thing` - is this right?

Why is it doing this and ignoring the registered editor and how can I make it stop doing this?

Comment: Can you please show a little more of the setAsText method above.

Comment: Updated - but the contents of this method is not the issue - when debugging it will never enter this method if the class has the String constructor.

Comment: Possibly because you are submitting a field with the same name as "someProperty", in that case it may not be calling the binder to create the "Thing" object, but using setter or the constructor to set the Property. It may be better to submit a property by name "thing" and then to explicitly put a @RequestParam(..), this may force the binder.

Comment: This behavior is still present in Spring 4.1.x (tested with 4.1.5), although it seems to be limited to collections of the target class. One workaround is to provide a static factory method instead of a constructor that accepts a single `String` argument.

Answer (score 0):

By introducing your own constructor, you disable the default constructor generated by compiler. Default constructor is probably required by the framework in order to be able to instantiate your Thing. If you really need your own constructor, you could also provide  a version without any parameters for framework's use.

Comment: Ths default constructor was also there - added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Lock the property name when you register the PropertyEditorSupport:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Thing.class, "someProperty", new ThingEditor());
}
```